# TableViewCell is not displaying any datas?

Tags: swift, uitableview

My TableViewCell don't displays the current data I get. Using printing I get all datas I need but the are not displayed in my TbleViewCell.

Here, I created a new class with all datas for the user and the posts:

```
class UserPostModel {
    var post: PostModel?
    var user: UserModel?

    init(post: PostModel, user: UserModel) {
        self.post = post
        self.user = user
    }
}
```

Declaration of my post array:

```
var postArray = [UserPostModel]()
```

Here, Im loading the datas into the new class:

```
self.observeRadius(completion: { (radius) in
                let currentRadius = radius
            // Üperprüfe, welche Posts im Umkreis erstellt wurden
                let circleQuery = geoRef.query(at: location!, withRadius: Double(currentRadius)!)

            circleQuery.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (postIds, location) in

                self.observePost(withPostId: postIds, completion: { (posts) in
                    guard let userUid = posts.uid else { return }
                    self.observeUser(uid: userUid, completion: { (users) in
                        let postArray = UserPostModel(post: posts, user: users)
                        self.postArray.append(postArray)
                        print(postArray.post!.postText!, postArray.user!.username!)
                        self.postArray.sort(by: {$0.post!.secondsFrom1970! > $1.post!.secondsFrom1970!})

                    })
                })
```

Here I'm loading the datas into the table view cells:

```
    extension DiscoveryViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    // wie viele Zellen
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(postArray.count)
        return postArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DiscoveryCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DiscoveryCollectionViewCell

        cell.user = postArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.post = postArray[indexPath.row]
        //cell.delegate = self

        return cell
    }
}
```

I now can display all informations with printing them out but they will be not displayed in my tableViewCell.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You append data to your array, but you don't reload TableView data.

To fix this, reload TableView data right after you append `UserPostModel` to your array

```
self.observeUser(uid: userUid, completion: { (users) in
    ...
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

Comment: sorry my mistake. I could be so easy ;) Thank you for your fast answer!!